# Android: OnNewIntent needs custom view size before inflating

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

I just want to calculate some line positions to draw in the onNewIntend(Intent intent) method. Given some lat/longitudes I have to fit them into a custom view.
For this calculation - and this is my problem - I need the myView.getHeight()/getWidth() methods which are 0, because onNewIntend(...) is invoked before onCreate(...). :/

Do you have any idea to cope with this issue?

I've already tried...

```
@Override
public void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    final String action = intent.getAction();

    if (Intent.ACTION_RUN.equals(action)) {         

        // @Todo: Here should be checked if view is already inflated ...
        setContentView(R.layout.collector);
        int x = mGraphView.getMeasuredHeight(); 
        ...
```

... and this yields to x=0, too

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Override onMeasure in your custom view to get the width and height whenever the views parent asks it to measure itself.  You can add a layout listener

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnLayoutChangeListener.html

```
@Override 
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec){
   int parentWidth = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
   int parentHeight = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
   this.setMeasuredDimension(parentWidth/2, parentHeight);
   this.setLayoutParams(new *ParentLayoutType*.LayoutParams(parentWidth/2,parentHeight));
   super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
```

}